# Is the DOM refreshed immediately using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an external JavaScript library to generate some formatted content. Let's call it `ExternalLibrary.GenerateGutterDivs()`

This code generates a table structure with some divs, something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="gutter">
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
       ...
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Once the table has been generate, I want to manipulate the generated DOM objects as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExternalLibrary.generateGutterDivs();

    alert("shomething"); //if I comment this I don't see the second alert

    $("td.gutter > div").each(function(index, val)
    {
        alert("gutterfound");
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that if I remove the first `alert("something")`, I don't see the second alert. This make think about the DOM maybe is not inmediatly **refreshed**. Do you know why I'm experiencing this situation?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Side comment: you should not be [using tables for layout](http://phrogz.net/CSS/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html).

Comment: Your guess may be correct, but I do not believe that it is. Instead of asking others to guess, the best way to solve your problem is to create a pared-down test case. Delete all HTML, CSS, and JS that do not affect the problem. Then do it again, and again, until you really, _really_ have NO superfluous code to confuse the issue. If you give that code to others, they can quickly reproduce your problem, help you understand the root cause, and provide you with a fix. _(And often, in the process of paring down the problem, you will figure out the problem yourself. :)_

Comment: And create a jsfiddle :) But in the worst case: Let `generateGutterDivs` accept a callback (although now that I think about it, this might not solve the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common issue. You should be returning a reference to the divs from `MyCode.generateGutterDivs()`, for example:

```
MyCode.generateGutterDivs = function () {
    var safeReference = $("<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>")
        .appendTo("td.gutter");
    return safeReference;
};
```

Then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var divs = MyCode.generateGutterDivs();

    divs.each(function(index, val)
    {
        alert("gutterfound"); // Should see 3 of these now
    });
</script>
```

Edit: Since modifying the library is not an option for the poster, I think a setTimeout for 0 milliseconds will do the trick, yielding to the browser to finish updating the DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyCode.generateGutterDivs();

    setTimeout(function () {
       divs.each(function(index, val)
       {
          alert("gutterfound"); // Should see 3 of these now
       });
    }, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: @box0: Thanks for your help. The problem is that the library is external. I have edited my post. Thanks anyway.

Comment: this works with 100ms. But this seems to be a dangerous solution. I will include a safety time, but I don't like this solution very much. Is there any other way for updating the DOM? I mean, Why is not it refreshed inmediatly? The code is synchronous, so I don't understand very much what is happenning?

Answer (score 1):

`MyCode.GenerateGutterDivs()` has not finished generating the DOM elements before the jQuery snippet is fired.  You'll need to modify `MyCode.GenerateGutterDivs()` to accept a callback function, something akin to this:

```
MyCode.GenerateGutterDivs(function() {
    $("td.gutter > div").each(function(index, val) {
        alert("gutterfound");
    });
});

//inside MyCode
GenerateGutterDivs = function(callback) {
    // Generate formatted content.
    callback();
};
```

Here's a proof of concept:  http://jsfiddle.net/gnbNt/2/

Comment: GenerateGutterDiv is an external library. I'll investigate if I can modify and distribute it under MIT license. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This callback will have the same effect... it won't wait till the DOM is finished updating.

Comment: I disagree, I do this all the time.

Comment: it may happen to work in some situations, but if you think about it, how is calling a callback different to returning? The callback is not being called asynchronously as in AJAX or event handlers.